# How do I resolve the correct DbContext type within ConfigureServices when multiple DbContexts are registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am trying to create a class that seeds user and role data.

My class that seeds data takes a `RoleManager` constructor parameter

```
public class IdentityDataSeeder
{
   private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;

   public IdentityDataSeeder(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
   {
      this.roleManager = roleManager;
   }

   public async Task SeedData()
   {
      // Do stuff with roleManager
   }
}
```

I call it from `Main` like this

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var dataSeeder = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IdentityDataSeeder>();
        await dataSeeder.SeedData();
    }

    host.Run();
}
```

I configure my dependenies like this (note that I have two `DbContexts` in my application; one context has my Identity tables, and the other context has my application tables).

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddDbContext<MyIdentityDbContext>(options =>
      options.UseSqlServer(
      Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultAdminConnection")));
   services.AddDbContext<MyApplicationDbContext>(options =>
      options.UseSqlServer(
      Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

   services.AddScoped<IdentityDataSeeder, IdentityDataSeeder>();
   services.AddScoped<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>, RoleStore<IdentityRole>>();
   services.AddScoped<RoleManager<IdentityRole>, RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
}
```

My two context classes look like this

```
public class MyIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
   // ...
}

public class MyApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
   // ...
}
```

When I run the program, I get the error

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.RoleStore1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.

I assume the problem is that since I have two `DbContext`s registered in my dependencies, the service provider can't figure out which one to use when it tries to resolve `RoleStore` (correct me if I'm wrong).

How do I tell the service provider to inject the `MyIdentityDbContext` dependency into `RoleStore`?

Comment: You are adding the same dbcontext twice. Even if it did resolve, how would it choose the one with the connection you intend? Create two dbcontexts, even if they are identical except for connection string.

Comment: I thought I was creating two different DbContexts?  Is there a different way to do it?

Comment: I would actually stick with one and manage Authorization with roles instead of juggling dbcontexts.

Comment: I am managing authorization with roles, but I want to customize the default ASP Identity tables, so don't I need to declare my own `DbContext` to do that?

Comment: maybe I'm not fully understanding what you are trying to do. But if you want two separate dbcontexts then you need two classes that derive from DbContext. I have a project where I have one DbContext for the identity tables and another for my application tables and they are two separate classes and DI works fine.

Comment: Both of the contexts that I'm registering do derive from DbContext.  I updated my question to show what they look like.

Comment: My bad. I totally read that as the same class. TGIF. I'm not sure what is wrong with RoleStore activation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the factory delegate with the [ActivatorUtilities Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities) that uses the specific `DbContext` resolved via the provider.

```
//...

services.AddScoped<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>>( sp => {
    DbContext context = sp.GetService<MyIdentityDbContext>();

    return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<RoleStore<IdentityRole>>(sp, context);
});

//...
```

When resolving the role store, the service provider will use the provided `DbContext` and resolve the remaining dependencies to be injected into the instance.